# How to add meta fields to custom taxonomy add/edit page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions, custom-field, css, child-theme

I have a custom taxonomy 'issue'. I tried to add some meta fields to the add/edit issue pages in the dashboard using the method explained by Ohad Raz (https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/).
So i downloaded the files from github (https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class), put them in the **child theme folder** & add these lines to **child theme functions.php**:

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/Tax-meta-class/Tax-meta-class.php' );

$config = array(
   'id' => 'demo_meta_box',
   'title' => 'Demo Meta Box',
   'pages' => array('issue'),
   'context' => 'normal',
   'fields' => array(),
   'local_images' => false,
   'use_with_theme' => false
);
$my_meta = new Tax_Meta_Class($config);
$my_meta->addText('text_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Text '));
$my_meta->addTextarea('textarea_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Textarea '));
$my_meta->addDate('date_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Date '));
$my_meta->addImage('image_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Image '));
$my_meta->addFile('file_field_id',array('name'=> 'My File '));
$my_meta->Finish();
```

So, now all fields are added to the add/edit taxonomy dashboard page. But, without the css style. Although there is a css file in the tax-meta-class folder/css, fields added to the dashboard have no style, even add image/add file buttons don't open, date picker is displayed as a normal text field.
I couldn't figure out how to apply the css code on those created fields. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code more & more I found the solution. So, for those who have interest in such thing:

1. change false to true in `use_with_theme`
2. change template path to stylesheet path in `tax-meta-class.php`

Cheers